# TypeError: props.onDateTimeUpdate is not a function

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using the code from [react-datetime-range](https://dishant15.github.io/react-datetime-range-super-picker/) and I'm having error while changing my date and time.

```js
const [to_date, setToDate] = useState(new Date())
    
    const handleFromDateUpdate = (date:any) => {
        setFromDate(date.date)
    }
    const handleToDateUpdate = (date:any) => {
        setToDate(date.date)
    }
    ...
    <DateTimePickerInput 
           from_date={from_date} 
           to_date={to_date}
           onFromDateTimeUpdate={this.handleFromDateUpdate} 
           onToDateTimeUpdate={this.handleToDateUpdate}
           theme="light" />
```

i tried finding solutions but after adding `this` wont help. I have no idea what to change.

Comment: where do you see the problem?

Comment: adding ```this``` would not have help with your issue unless you are writing it as a class base component. Would be better if you can provide the full code snippet that you are using right now.

Comment: @RinkeshGolwala On the localhost. This error pops out when I click to change the date and time

Comment: @user2232355 [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-leaf-cu6x6?file=/src/App.js) you go.. Scroll down to the date picker, it's locate right above the map. The error occurs when I click to change the date and time

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `DateTimePickerInput` which requires an `onDateTimeUpdate` prop.
You seem to be passing props that match better with the `DateTimeRangePicker` picker.

Comment: Oh yeahh i changed back to `DateTImeRangePicker` and it worked! What changes do i need to do so that it would work on the `DateTimePickerInput`? Cause i prefer the latter one more

Comment: From the docs 
```
   <DateTimePicker date={curr_date}
    onDateTimeUpdate={handleDateUpdate} />
```

And note that it's `DateTimePicker` not `DateTimePickerInput`

Comment: @John not sure if I understands what you are trying to do correctly...... but have you tried ```import {DateTimeRangePicker as DateTimePickerInput} from "react-datetime-range-super-picker"```;

Comment: That is assuming that you want to name it as ```DateTimePickerInput``` instead of using the original naming convention.

Comment: Ok i worked when i changed to `DateTimeRangePickerInput`